Firebase cloud messaging integration in flutter
I connected firebase cloud messaging to my flutter app, i am receiving push notifications successfully, but then i connected my flutter app to a custom backend connected to firebase cloud messaging and i am only receiving messages in foreground, not in background. Can anyone suggest any possible reasons for this issue ?
Here is my response structure:
`


{

          message: {

            token: device_token,

            notification: {

              title: params[:title],

              body: params[:body],

            },

            data: params[:data],

            webpush: {

              notification: {

                title: params[:title],

                body: params[:title],

                click_action: params[:click_action],

                actions: params[:web_actions]

}

            },

            android: {

              notification: {

                click_action: params[:click_action],

                title: params[:title],

                body: params[:body],

              }

            },

            apns: {

              payload: {

                aps: {

                  category: "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"

                }

              }

            }

          }

        }


`
Here is my functions in Flutter to receive messages from FCM:
`FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

        // dispatcher.enableAndMakeCanvasVisible();

        print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');



        logMessage(message);



        print('Notification not null');



        String url = message.data['path'];

        print(url);

        GoRouter.of(context).go(url);

      });



      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

        // dispatcher.enableAndMakeCanvasVisible();

        print('Got a message onMessageOpenedApp!');



        logMessage(message);



        print('Notification not null');



        String url = message.data['path'];

        print(message.data);

        print(url);



        GoRouter.of(context).go(url);

      });
`

I tried to imitate the response i.e. RemoteMessage from Firebase console, but they appear to me mostly same except message.notification?.android?.tag which is campaign_collapse_key_6393197284280654770 from FCM, but null in my server, response, i.e. RemoteMessage.
